# Twitter data set collection for analysis

Tags: twitter

I am working on to gather a dataset for Twitter . Basically i want to store all tweets from current date back to twitter limit ( i guess 14 days).

I would be using this data for analysis.

Found this:

https://twitter.com/search-advanced
http://www.quora.com/Twitter-1/Whats-the-best-way-to-crawl-Twitter

but was not very helpful for me.

Comment: Were you able to find anything related to this?